# Laplacian of a function at points of extrema

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-topology

Consider a smooth function $f$ on a compact manifold $M$. Let $p$ be a point where $f$ is maximum and $q$ be a point where $f$ is minimum. Do we necessarily have $\Delta f|_p \leq 0$ and $\Delta f|_q \geq 0$?

Comment: And your thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If a smooth function $f$ of one variable has a local max at $p,$ could $f''(p) > 0?$